# Gesture recogniser in different class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was wondering if this was possible.
To have a class which adds new imageViews to the main view and assigns a gesture recogniser to it.

So in my view builder class, I have the following:

```
UIImageView *headerPlusIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plusIcon.png"]];
headerPlusIcon.frame = CGRectMake(header.frame.size.width - 2.5*(logoSize - 8), yPosition*1.6, logoSize*0.9, logoSize*0.9);
headerPlusIcon.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UIGestureRecognizer *headerTapGesture = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:mainView action:@selector(testTapGesture:)];
[headerPlusIcon addGestureRecognizer:headerTapGesture];
```

The tap gesture method goes like this:

```
-(void)testTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    });
}
```

mainView is passed into this class via the constructor and is simply the main view.

This is called like this:

```
mainViewbuilder = [[MainViewBuilder alloc] initWithBaseView:self.view];
[mainViewbuilder buildHeader];
```

Unfortunately the tap gesture method never gets called... how would this be done properly?
Thanks!

Comment: Looks perfectly normal to me. Are you observing any problems with this approach?

Comment: The tap gesture method never gets called.. when I tap on the icon, nothing happens.

If I move the code to the main view controller, it runs as expected

Comment: I suggest you simply to use a uibutton with The image setted

Comment: Unfortunately, a button was considered but we're going to have other objects which will be irregularly shaped with transparencies as well as require pan gesture recognition..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `UITapGestureRecognizer`

[Apple Docs on UITapGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitapgesturerecognizer_class/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion!  I have to admit I was skeptical but it seems to have done the trick :) had to change the target to self and it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted never adds your headerPlusIcon to the view hierarchy. You say in your answer to Adam that you got it working, but I don't see how if you don't add the headerPlusIcon to your view controller's content view hierarchy somewhere.

Note that mucking around in a view controller's view hierarchy from outside is not good object-oriented design.

It would be better to have the view controller ask another object for a view (probably through a protocol) and then add that view itself.

Comment: Hi, I didn't show the whole method.  It adds the the imageview to the mainview as a subview.  But the point to have the controller add the object to the view instead sounds more ideal.  Will consider that, thanks!